# Is there a bug with "min" and "max" attributes on "type:date"?

Tags: html

CSS:

```css
.in-range-test input:in-range {
  background-color: lime;
}

.in-range-test input:out-of-range {
  background-color: red;
}

.in-range-test input:in-range+label:after {
  content: 'Okay';
  color: lime;
}

.in-range-test input:out-of-range+label:after {
  content: 'Not okay';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="in-range-test">
  <form>
    <input type="date" min="2000-05-30" max="2001-06-30">
    <label>Your number is: </label>
  </form>

</div>
```

The "min" and "max" restrictions work fine if you click on the "date" calendar, however, if you use the keyboard to set a date beyond the allowed range, it starts working in a very abnormal way, defying the restrictions set by "min" and "max" attributes.

For example, if you manually set the year to 5555, the day to 31, then every second or third month is "valid". If you set the day to 30 or below, then only February becomes valid. Setting the date to a date lower than the "min" restricted date also results in an abnormal behavior.

Is this some sort of a bug?

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox works just fine.

Comment: Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Part of the issue is that when usign the "date" calendar the browser will normalize the input to the "yyyy--mm-dd" format which can be compared to min/max. When using text input a date field can technically be in many other format resulting in what you are experiencing. A way around that is to use a regex pattern to force input format such as:

```html
<input type="date" min="2000-05-30" max="2001-06-30" pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}">
```

Of course there is also the fact that not all browsers implement things the same/correctly but that's a per browser issue.

Comment: `pattern` has no effect in `<input>` elements with type `date`.

Comment: @D.Pardal it is supported in date input. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Setting_maximum_and_minimum_dates

Comment: No, it's not and it wouldn't make sense if it was. In [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes), you can clearly see that the `pattern` attribute is only supported by the types `password`, `text` or `tel`.

Comment: It's because date is technically a calendar popup. When that fails the fallback is a text element which supports pattern, OP is using fallback. Hence pattern is supported  and MDN even has an example.

Comment: @D.Pardal Pattern CAN be used with Date.